# Open source download manager for YouTube, Vimeo, etc

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, download-manager

I am looking for a download manager that has the following features:

- **Open source** because I want to contribute, so I am looking for a download manger which is open source.
- Free.
- Compatible with Windows. It would be nice if it is multi-platform.
- Like Internet Download Manager (IDM); it can download from YouTube, Vimeo, etc. websites **(very very important to me)**. With IDM running, if a user opens YouTube or Vimeo and plays a video it pops up a "Download" window (small window at the corner of the video). Clicking on that window then starts the download. It even asks you what kind of video quality you prefer. I haven't found a open source download manager that can do this.

Comment: Welcome to SR, Sami! If there are any specific things you like about IDM and want to see in the recommended alternatives, but you've not (yet) mentioned them in your question: please [edit] it and do so. Imagine you're the only one ever heard of IDM, so we're completely blank about it :) For some guidance, you can take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185). Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the exception of the pop-up integration I would suggest taking a look at [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

- Small
- Open Source & Gratis
- Supports downloading from 100s of sites, including youtube, vimeo.
- Allows selection of quality and if you have [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) installed as well will convert files if the requested format is not available for download.
- Cross platform, including Windows
- Written in python, *but there is a windows installer with it's own python*.

The only downside is that it is a command line utility - find the item that you would like to download in your browser, pause the play, copy the URL and in a command window type: `youtube-dl the_url` *with optional flags for quality, format, etc.* and it works very quickly.

Comment: pop-up integration would be nice though! but overall this project looks promising!