# Windows command line software to produce pieces of videos between start/end time

Tags: windows, windows-10, video-editing

I'm looking for software that would:

1. Run on Windows command line
2. As input, accepts a video file name, start time and end time and a new file name.
3. Produces a new file which is a chunk of video between start and end time

**Required features:**

- Supports Windows 10+ (However, if an ideal product exists that only supports XP or Windows 8, I would accept the answer. But no Linux-only stuff please)
- Has command line interface (don't care if it has GUI or not)
- Gratis, or very cheap (under $5-$10 USD)
- As input, at the very least, supports `.m4a` and ideally `.webm` video files as produced by *[`youtube-dl`](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31400/open-source-download-manager-for-youtube-vimeo-etc/31406#31406)*

**Desired optional features**

- Accept a set of start/end time pairs; and stitch together several chunks of the file specified by those pairs.

**Things I don't care about**

- Fancy video editing other than "cut from here to there" aren't required. No need for transitions etc...
- Format of the output video, as long as it's something VLC can play. Does NOT have to be same format as input video file.
- Whether it's the same product or a set of utilities. E.g. if it is something that requires `ffmpeg`, it's fine.
- Any reasonable dependencies are OK. E.g. "need to have powershell" or "need to have Perl 6 installed" or "Need to have Windows Python installed" etc... are fine.
- Speed. Doesn't have to be super speedy
- Open source and other code licensing issues
- Precise way of specifying inputs is irrelevant as long as it can be done from command line and has enough flexibility to support required/optional features.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg does all that

```
ffmpeg -i source.m4a -ss 00:00:30.0 -c copy -to 00:00:40.0 output.m4a
```